# React: How to redirect to another url if the user is logged in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect the user to `/dashboard` if the user is logged in but I am facing this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

My Home Component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.login);

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    props.history.push("/dashboard"); // This line is producing the error
    window.location.reload();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I tried the same approach(`props.history.push("/dashboard");`) with my Login component but I did not get any error. I want to know why this error occurred and how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried doing it via the useHistory hook provided by react-router-dom

Comment: @RobertTerrell No, I didn't know about that. How to use it?

Comment: I added an answer outlining its use

Comment: @noobprogrammer https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'


const Home = () => {

const history = useHistory()
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.login);



  useEffect(()=> {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      history.push("/dashboard"); // This line is producing the error
  }
  },[isLoggedIn, history]) //also add history dependency

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Trell this seems to work but the only problem is that ```window.location.reload();``` this keeps on reloading the whole page.

Comment: you can remove that line as it is not necessary

Comment: without that line nothing is happening meaning I am not being redirected to the dashboard

Comment: try it within a useEffect

Comment: just small edit you have to make. add ```history``` as a dependency too in the useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Home` component is most likely *not* wrapped in a `Route` so the `history` is not passed in. This is why `Login` can access `history`.

You can use the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook here:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = (props) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  const history = useHistory();

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    history.push("/dashboard");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: thanks for answering but useHistory is not working. Meaning I am not being redirected to the dashboard